# Codeigniter 3 memcached issue

Tags: php, windows, caching, codeigniter-3, memcached

i'm getting this error in my drivers/Cache_memcached.php file

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: drivers/Cache_memcached.php

Line Number: 120

i have downloaded 5.6 memcached ptted in php/ext/ but i'm getting this error in CI3 with  php 5.6
i'm getting $this->_config = NULL value

please help me out anyone thanx in advance

Comment: It's been awhile but I want to say that I had to edit the code and simply bypass the error. Otherwise determine why $this->_config is NULL as I assume your config should have data.